# foreign key appearing as char field

Tags: python, django

My foreign key that is event_id is being displayed as another attribute in my Expense class as Hall_name which is an attribute of Event class a char field. i don't know why because i have just did this.

```
class Event(model.Model):
    event_hall=models.CharField(max_length=1)
    here are all my attributes but i let django make its own default primary key and it should be an integer.
class Expense(models.Model)
    event_id=models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

so why is it displaying it as event_hall in my foreign key?

Comment: where you can see `event_hall` is it in django-admin?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your problem you want this :

```
class Event(model.Model):
      event_hall=models.CharField(max_length=1)

      def __str__(self): # define this method
            return self.event_hall


class Expense(models.Model)
      event_id=models.ForeignKey(Event)
```